# Assign new ID to each row dynamically

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with over 9000 rows. Each row has some weird ID. I would like to re-set each ID as following 000001,000002,000003, etc... (dynamically). Is there an easy way of doing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can update the value to a number:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*, row_number() over (order by (select null)) as new_id
      from t
     )
update toupdate
    set id = new_id;
```

Or if you want a zero-padded, 6 digit, formatted number:

```
update toupdate
    set id = format(new_id, '000000');
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `row_number` as follows:

```
Select t.*,
       Row_number() over (order by id) as new_id
  From t
```